# User input to txt file on a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to add a user input on bash to a txt file but when I open the file it only show the text written on the code. Here is the code...

```
if [ $opcao2==1 ]
then
echo "Esolheu Inserir uma antena"
echo "Nome: "
read $nome
echo "fornecedor:"
read $fornecedor
echo "Preco: "
read $preco
echo "Sinais: "
read $sinais
echo "Nome:" $nome  >> antenas.txt
```

Comment: Don't use `$` when `read`ing variables. `$` is used to *get* the value of a variable, not to *set* it. Also, you should almost always put double-quotes around variables when you do use them (e.g. `"Nome: $nome"` Finally, you need spaces between elements in a test (and single-equal is standard in this context). so use `if [ [ "$opcao2" = 1 ]`. I recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) for spotting common mistakes like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ "$opcao2" = 1 ]
then
echo "Esolheu Inserir uma antena"
echo "Nome: "
read nome
echo "Nome:" $nome  >> antenas.txt
```

important is the read statement. It is vital to understand, that you are setting the variable without the dollar in front and using the variable's value with $.

Therefore no $ in the read statement, but in the echo we need it to use the value of the variable.

Comment: @YellowRedStrings :  Also note that `>>` is appending to a file. If you have trouble when first writing your code, and then look at the top of your file, you may think that nothing has changed. Either use `> file` (which creates a new file each time) or use `tail file` to see the newest info added to your `file`. Good luck to all.